# auth0 redirect to http://localhost:4200/null after direct login

Tags: angular, auth0

I try to implement access management with auth0 following [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/real-world-angular-series-part-4/). It works well when I access a protected route with an auth guard but when I login directly I am redirected to the following url :

> http://localhost:4200/null

While I expect the root path http://localhost:4200 as behavior expected.

I checked on the [repo of the tutorial](https://github.com/auth0-blog/mean-rsvp-auth0/) to confirm my code but I don't find anything special. Maybe you have any inputs to solve this problem?

Below my code :

**auth.service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {

  / ... /

handleAuth() {
  // When Auth0 hash parsed, get profile
  this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
    if (authResult && authResult.accessToken) {
      window.location.hash = '';
      this.getProfile(authResult);
    } else if (err) {
      this.clearRedirect();
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      console.error(`Error authenticating: ${err.error}`);
    }
  });
}

private getProfile(authResult) {
  this.loggingIn = true;
  // Use access token to retrieve user's profile and set session
  this.auth0.client.userInfo(authResult.accessToken, (err, profile) => {
    if (profile) {
      this.setSession(authResult, profile);
      this.redirect();
    } else if (err) {
      console.warn(`Error retrieving profile: ${err.error}`);
    }
  });
}

private redirect() {
  const redirect = decodeURI(localStorage.getItem('authRedirect'));
  const navArr = [redirect || '/'];

  this.router.navigate(navArr);
  // Redirection completed; clear redirect from storage
  this.clearRedirect();
```

}

From my understanding of the tutorial, the line `const navArr = [redirect || '/'];` should navigates to the stored redirect URL or the homepage. But in my case it redirect to `http://localhost:4200/null` when I login directly and not the homepage.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your localstorage object `authRedirect` can be null and thus users can be redirected to `http://localhost:4200/null`

You should check if the value is null and redirect users to the homepage (`/`) when it is.

```
 private _redirect() {
    var redirect = localStorage.getItem('authRedirect') && decodeURI(localStorage.getItem('authRedirect'));


    if (!redirect || redirect == null)
    {
      //redirect is null so set route to homepage
      redirect = "/";
    }

    const navArr = [redirect || '/'];
    this.router.navigate(navArr);
    // Redirection completed; clear redirect from storage
    this._clearRedirect();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround but the problem is not really solved :

```
{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: '',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

Comment: I don't really think this solved it. What happens is that your users are redirected to http://localhost:4200/null because your 'const navArr' is null after they login. You just catched it by setting a wildcard route... Not the best solution in my opinion.